# Does the stack frame for main have a saved frame pointer and a saved return address?

Tags: c++, c, callstack

In the stack frame of the main function of a C\C++ program, is there a saved return adress and a saved stack pointer (ebp)? If so, where do they point to, since there was no previous stack frame to record?

Comment: None of this is part of the C or C++ language specifications. Those are implementation details, and any implementation can deal with this as it sees fit. `main` is usually not the entry point as far as the OS is concerned. The real entry point is often part of the language support implementations (e.g. the CRT).

Comment: Generally speaking yes, but as @IInspectable already pointed out, this is an implementation detail and not guaranteed by neither C nor C++ standard.

Comment: For C++, the language requires that certain code can be executed before `main`, which implies that something in userland is responsible for calling them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C\C++ binaries created by gcc, MSVC and probably other compilers as well have an entry point `_start` which is part of the library and gets statically linked into the executable. The ELF/PE loader of the operating system sets up a stack for the program to run and upon scheduling, the CPU *returns* to `_start` which then does some library specific setup and calls `main`. So upon invocation of `main`, there is a stored return address which goes back to the clib function which then uses a system call to notify the OS to terminate the program.

However, as pointed out by the comments, this is not defined by the language standard itself, just the way it is most commonly implemented in existing systems.

Comment: There is no symbol called `_start` in MSVC's CRT implementation. The entry point for a Unicode console application is called `wmainCRTStartup`.